# Query table columns by using 'desc tablename' command via PetaPoco

Tags: .net, database, orm, petapoco

I want to get the columns info of a table in a Mysql database, and I use the micro-orm library [PetaPoco](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco). My code is as follows:

```
var cols=db.Query<dynamic>("desc t_sometable").ToList();
```

But it throws an exception saying

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc t_sometable' at line 1
```

I am new to PetaPoco. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: DESC is short for descending. You should use DESCRIBE. I don't know if it will work, though.

Comment: Try using a semi colon before the statement (this tells PetaPoco to run the command as is) `var cols=db.Query<dynamic>(";desc t_sometable").ToList();`

Comment: Thank you Eduardo!  Adding a semicolon really works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a semicolon.  This prevents PetaPoco from trying to add columns names to what it thinks will be a Select

```
var cols=db.Query<dynamic>(";desc t_sometable").ToList();
```

https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/issues/22